# Is it ok to say: Peter and John "agree"?

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number

If I say Peter "agrees", I think that the verb agrees must have the "s" at the end because Peter is a third person.

On the other hand, if I say Peter and John "agrees", it is wrong, because there are two people involved in this phrase, so I must eliminate the "s" at the end of the verb.

Is it ok?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine. The subject is plural, so the verb needs to be plural.

---

There are other ways it could be written if, for some reason, you don't like the existing phrasing:

> Peter and John **agree** *with each other*.
>   Peter and John are **in agreement**.
>   Peter **agrees** with John, *and vice-versa*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

The verb *to agree* conjugates as:

> I agree
>   You agree
>   He/she agrees
>   We agree
>   They agree

Peter and John together would be replaced by the pronoun *they*, so *Peter and John agree* is equivalent to *they agree*.